# How is an academic course structured in its content (USA)?

Tags: united-states, university

I don’t even know if “course” is the better word choice in the title of this question.

Those things may be obvious for Americans, but it’s tricky to understand the elements of the academic life in a given country because the words are similar or the same in other countries, but with different meanings. I searched those meanings, but it’s hard to understand them isolated and without examples (how they usually appear). I assume those things are too obvious to be explained (even by colleges themselves), but only learned in practice. If someone has a link to a college explaining the structure of what it teaches through a diagram I would be amazed.

If I want to become, for instance, a Nutritionist, I would get into a Nutrition ____ (program?/course?) in order to earn a Nutrition ____ (degree?). When people ask me what I do in college, I answer that I ____ (study? / am coursing?/ am majoring in?) Nutrition. In this semester I have a _____ (course?/subject?) called Physiopathology of Nutrition II that is really hard.

Comment: To be a nutritionist you have to write the word "Nutritionist" on a piece of paper and hand it to yourself. Mission accomplished.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's mostly about the English language.  Consider the English Language Learners site.

Comment: Also, the title makes the question unclear.

Comment: "I am coursing in" is nonsensical/incorrect English, but all your other suggested terms are fine. The words course, subject and degree are all somewhat interchangeable, at least in the UK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the US, a "course" typically means one subject studied for about four months, earning about 3 or 4 "credits" toward graduation. A "semester" will consist of about 5 (maybe 4) courses with a total credit load of 16 or so. Students can take a bit more in a given semester if they are up for the work. A full program (degree) would be something like 16 * 8 credits, but maybe a bit more or less. It isn't uniform, however, and some colleges count things differently.

Normally there are two semesters or "terms" per year, with a summer break, but some universities have four shorter semesters, with students typically studying for three out of the four. This is usually called the "quarter system", and it isn't typical.

A major is around 16-18 courses, minimum, out of a total undergraduate "program" of around 32 courses. Students in the US normally get a general education, so a math major will also study science, history, philosophy, writing, literature, and a few other things as well.

It is usually possible to have two majors, say math and philosophy, but it isn't typical. Your diploma will mention your major, though you studied lots of other things as well. If you successfully complete the math major you have a math degree.

What in UK might be called a "course" or "course of study" is more like a major, but not precisely since a UK degree is probably more specialized than one in US. But here a "course" is fine grained: Calculus II, or Physics I.

In the US you would say "I'm studying Nutrition and I just finished a course in Physiopathology" or something like that (not my field). Upon completion you have a degree in Nutrition. Your "major" is also your "major subject", say nutrition, or math.

Comment: Can “subject” be used interchangeably with “course” in college, or is it a more appropriate when referring to school (until ninth grade)?

Comment: Yes, and also with major. A subject could be Calculus I, though it would be more likely to be called a course. And "what subject do you study" might also just be "math". It isn't that precise. The terminology carries over to secondary school. The "subject" might be math, or it might be Algebra II, for example. So the granularity will vary depending on the conversation. If you ask a secondary school teacher what subject they teach, they might say math. If you ask what subject are you teaching now they might say Geometry. But the same would be true of a university professor, depending.

Comment: If I speak to another computer scientist, and asked about my "subject", I'll use a fine grained interpretation. In speaking to my cousin, the plumber, I'll keep it general. I teach Algorithms or I teach CS, respectively.